# How to use for command to specify part of list

Tags: java

I am trying to do a task where I have to write a program that produces a comma separated list depending on how many entries are in it, the specifics are below:

With Youtube, keeping track of your likes is very important. When people view one of your pages, you
want to advertise it to the world. So, as you collect the list of people who have watched your tutorials,
you want to send out a message.
To test this idea, suppose you receive a comma-separated list of names and you want to use that list to
send the following messages:

1. If the list is empty, dispatch the message “No one likes this.“ (and try again with a new video.)
2. If the list contains 1 to 3 names, dispatch the message “X likes this.“, “X and Y like this.“, or
   “X, Y, and Z like this.“, depending upon the situation.
3. If the list contains 4+ names, dispatch the message “X, Y, and ??? others like this.“, where ???
   is the appropriate number, in addition to X and Y.
   In your test program, the comma-separated list of people will simply come from a user input. Duplicate
   names are okay for now. Write the code to receive such input.

**The code I have created thus far is below**

```
    import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("C");

    

   for (int list = 0;)
   {
            System.out.println(list.get(0) + "likes this");
                 }
    }
}
```

I should be receiving the phrase "Ben likes this", however I am met with the following error:

```
    /Main.java:16: error: illegal start of expression
   for (int list = 0;)
                 ^
1 error
```

Any advice on how to fix this is greatly appreciated

Comment: You start a for loop declaration, but then instead of actually writing a for loop, you decide to declare a new variable `list` and assign `0` to it.  That has nothing to do with looping, so the compiler is very confused.  So am I.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new to java and don't know how to take input, use
the code below

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Please enter a comma separated list of people who likes this video:");
String readLine = br.readLine();
if(readLine!=null && !readLine.isEmpty()){
String[] names = readLine.split(",");
if(names.length==1) System.out.println(names[0]+" likes this");
else if(names.length==2) System.out.println(names[0]+" and "+names[1]+" like this");
else if(names.length==3) System.out.println(names[0]+","+names[1]+" and "+names[2]+" like this");
else if(names.length>=4) System.out.println(names[0]+","+names[1]+" and "+(names.length-2)+" others like this");
}
br.close();
```